# Placing 2 divs side by side using mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

Is there some way to use the [styled](https://mui.com/system/styled/) utility from mui to place 2 divs side by side?

None of the examples in the documentation cover this particular use case.

The answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17217766/two-divs-side-by-side-fluid-display) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21476863/place-2-div-side-by-side) address this, but not within the context of mui / material ui.

I tried the following, but the Box elements end up on separate lines:

```
import React from 'react';
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";

const Wrapper = styled(Box)({
  display: "grid",
});

const App = (props) => {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Wrapper>
        <Box>text here</Box>
        <Box>more text</Box>
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  )
}

export default App
```

How can I modify the above code to get both lines of text on the same line?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] and some debugging details.

Comment: Can this be re-opened now that a reproducible example was added?

Comment: Mui has a component <Stack> https://mui.com/material-ui/react-stack/

Comment: Can this question be re-opened now that a reproducible example was added?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are multiple ways. You can use Grid, Box, and Styled components.

Here are two examples using `Grid` and `Box with styled` components.

A working example on [Codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/mui-5-forked-j2c9j8?file=/src/App.js:0-763)

```js
import * as React from "react";
import Box from "@mui/material/Box";
import Grid from "@mui/material/Grid";
import { styled } from "@mui/material/styles";
import { Container } from "@mui/material";

const Wrapper = styled(Box)({
  display: "grid",
  gridTemplateColumns: "repeat(2, 1fr)",
  gridGap: 8,
  marginTop: 16
});

export default function App() {
  return (
    <Container>
      <Grid xs={12} sx={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }} container>
        <Grid xs={6} sx={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }} item>
          div one
        </Grid>
        <Grid xs={6} sx={{ border: "1px solid #ccc" }} item>
          div two
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
      <Wrapper>
        <Box>div one</Box>
        <Box>div two</Box>
      </Wrapper>
    </Container>
  );
}
```

Comment: This is exactly what I needed. Someone please consider reopening this question now that I've added a minimal reproducible example. Thanks!